# How to install mcrypt in xampp for php 7.2 version in windows

Tags: php

I installed mcrypt using the command :

```
     pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

but after installation i'm getting a warning error like this :

```
     WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix .exe, but 
     config variable php_suffix does not match
     ERROR: The DSP mcrypt.dsp does not exist.
```

I'm using php version 7.2.6 in windows .
When i checked the

```
     <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I can't find the mcrypt enabled .
The path used to install the mcrypt is **c:\xampp\php**